# Append selected items to a list

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dropdown

I want to create a dropdown box with a few items. Once the user selects the item and clicks the '+' button, the item is added below to a 'basket' section. They should be able to add multiple items over and over.

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
  var a = document.getElementById("selection");
  var item = a.options[a.selectedIndex].text;

  document.getElementById("basket").innerHTML = item;
  var counter = 1;
  while (counter <= 1) {
    var list = document.write(item);
    counter++;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Select your items!</h1>

<form id="myForm">
  <p>Item:
    <select id="selection">
      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
      <option value="3">three</option>
      <option value="4">four</option>
    </select>
    <button id="button">+</button></p>
</form>

<br><br><br>

<h1>Basket</h1>

<p id="basket"></p>
```

When the button is pressed, all current content disappears and the item selected appears on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button in the form has **no** `type="button"`. Therefore it is used as submit button and that's why you get *the* blank page.

You don't need a loop.

#### Example

```js
var button = document.getElementById("button");
var select = document.getElementById("select");
var basket = document.getElementById("basket");

// Add text
function addToBasket() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  basket.appendChild(li);
}

button.addEventListener("click", addToBasket);
```

```html
<h1>Select your items!</h1>

<form id="myForm">

  <p>Item:
    <select id="select">

      <option value="1">one</option>
      <option value="2">two</option>
      <option value="3">three</option>
      <option value="4">four</option>

    </select>

    <button id="button" type="button">+</button></p>

</form>

<h1>Basket</h1>

<ul id="basket"></ul>
```

Comment: This is almost what i need, i want it to display the inner html though rather than the value, e.g. "one" instead of "1". Also i need them in a list format with items appearing below one another when the button is clicked, e.g. Bread, Milk, Beans

Comment: `li.textContent` is alot better performance-wise than `li.innerHTML` if you don't need HTML parsing of the content.

Answer (score 0):

You are not concatenating them. `document.getElementById("basket").innerHTML = item;` removes everything in the basket and add only the selected one.

Use this to concatenate the new item with what already exists in the basket `document.getElementById("basket").innerHTML += item;`. You can style it to make the basket look nice.

Comment: Ive added this in, but once the button is pressed im still getting the same outcome with the item being added to a blank page